# WSO2 ESB rest service invocation example

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can anyone point me to a full-fledged REST service invocation form wso2 ESB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the articles written by Hiranya [1] [2].

These articles provides a very good explanation on WSO2 ESB REST API support.

[1]. http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-get-cup-of-coffee-wso2-way.html

[2]. http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/09/get-cup-coffee-wso2-way

Hope this helps!

/Harshana